# GOJS exporting the canvas diagram as an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, gojs

I am using the GOJS javascript framework to work with flowcharts. I have a pretty huge flowchart that isn't fully visible in the viewport. There is a scrollbar to view the hidden content in the canvas.

I am trying to export the canvas as an image. But I am only able to export the visible part in the canvas and not the full flowchart. I have tried using canvas.toDataURL() and the GOJS diagram.makeImageData() APIs, but haven't been successful.

Could the JS experts here please help me out? Thanks so much...

Comment: Also consider rendering as SVG: http://gojs.net/latest/intro/makingSVG.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be touching the Canvas element inside the Diagram's DIV element.

Have you read http://gojs.net/latest/intro/makingImages.html ? You need to pass some options to **Diagram.makeImageData**.

Comment: Thank you @walter! Passing the parameter {scale: 1} to the makeImageData() API helped.